# Android device Serial number winforms c#

Tags: c#, android, winforms, usb, serial-number

I have a problem with reading the serial number from the USB Android Device and write it to the label in Windows Forms C#. I have tried to dig in WMI using WQL but I didn't find the Serial Number property.
[SerialNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC8jT.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Query in many WMI classes. ManagementObjectSearcher s =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
       @"SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity where DeviceID Like ""USB%""");

Comment: and this:Win32_USBHub, Win32_POTSModem,Win32_PnPSignedDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to do this. There is a NuGet called "PortableDevices". If someone is looking for it everything is [HERE](https://cgeers.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/enumerating-windows-portable-devices/)